# How to auto accept permission in android 7 - API 25

Tags: android

I read many the same question and I know since Android 6 permission must accept by user.

My device is not really a phone(that's point different with other question). It's just use snap chip, android 7 platform and have not screen touch, no keyboard button.
I am using Vysor software to connect my device and click accept permission through the  emulator screen of vysor.

And my app will not push to CHplay, it's immediate loading to the device.
thank you for any solve.

Comment: You're saying that you can't accept the permission through Vysor? If that's so, you can try system overlay permission for Vysor to accept the permission. I've personally experienced this that you can't accept permission through Vysor, you've to use actual device to do that. But, the system overlay permission might help.

Comment: Or, if that's the case, why not root the device and override permissions?

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I mean I have to accept permission using Vysor, that's lost more time for producer department. And I have not knowledge about linux kernel, I think root the device is hard choice.